# How to Use the DFT (FFT) to Solve a Least Squares Regularization Problem (Inverse Problem)?

Tags: image-processing, deconvolution, optimization, least-squares, inverse-problem

Let $X$ and $K$ be an image and a Point Spread Function (PSF), respectively.

The blurred image $B$ is obtained as follows

$$B = X * K$$

I want to solve the following general regularization problem

$$\min_X \left\|X * K - B\right\|_2^2 + \lambda \| f(X) \|_2^2$$

where $f$ is a regularization function. In some literature (e.g. [Blur kernel estimation via salient edges and low rank prior for blind image deblurring](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0923596517301340)) I have seen, the authors use the FFT to solve such a problem. However, I cannot find any resources that show the procedure. My questions are:

1. How one can use FFT to solve the above problem?
2. Is there any condition that must be satisfied to use FFT?

Comment: The problem itself has an optimization based solution, I believe the literature you had mentioned use FFT for calculating PSF.

Comment: Does $*$ denote convolution?  What does "PSF" stand for?

Comment: It would be much easier for us if you can cite some literatures where authors use FFT.

Comment: @Azevedo Yes. Point Spread Function. Also blurring kernel.

Comment: @AlexTP for example this paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0923596517301340, eq. 11 and 12.

Comment: You could use fourier transform to pose this as an optimization problem in frequency domain (convolution turns into multiplication).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question really depends on $ f \left( \cdot \right) $.
Yet in order to show how to use FFT we can even use 1D signals.

Let's rewrite the problem:

$$ \hat{x} = \arg \min_{x} \frac{1}{2} \left\| K x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} \left\| f \left( x \right) \right\|_{2}^{2} $$

The derivative is given by:

$$ g = {K}^{T} \left( K x - b \right) + \lambda f' \left( x \right)^{T} f \left( x \right) $$

Now, $ K $ as a matrix is given by a [Circulant Convolution Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).
Hence the operation $ K v $ or $ {K}^{T} v $ can be done in the Fourier Domain.
Under some circumstances it might accelerate the operation significantly.